# wildcard in playwright page.frame (url option)

Tags: typescript, url, css-selectors, webautomation, playwright

I'm trying to find a way to use a wildcard in the `page.frame(url)` function of playwright, I have this code:

```js
await page.frame({
    url: 'http://192.168.20.222:8080/ords/f?p=150:13:12188371642929::NO:13::&cs=3rW0d3IdG36wpBBz1GAnD2UV8kf7xWvgqUaa28l5eceRm71VjW6F33ufnHQnEvSAJpbB7CSDdVQNXeKOyLRYnQw&p_dialog_cs=IBgwSu6yIUBbITteHHI5ea8wU7JXa9CDY1LsEMKeBVEM7oYixeWw0HW9GrCAtCPffvG3VLlveff_t720koyh3Q'
}).click('button[id="B5602689567386780"]');
```

and when I open the same page with the test tool the url changes:

```js
await page.frame({
    url: 'http://192.168.20.222:8080/ords/f?p=150:13:1511883080952::NO:13::&cs=3DJ0vt7NMVCCk4xQvKJoD-unSF5896wbfp99oGMQ0Qg7DaIbaeJOV0oqnEfkntXgnLNq902F97vpFAm2-dlFGRQ&p_dialog_cs=Ui4xj5jDt_J91vpSWo-MezLxSG60jFLoGhx3oh85DTIaR7Tv9c7wdCSXRRikra57RyQz2hvkPzZEXNqbwqF83g'
}).click('button[id="B5602689567386780"]');
```

Do I have any option to use a wildcard in the url?

Like `*` and have my code like this?

`url: 'http://192.168.20.222:8080/ords/f?p=150:*'`

Answer (score 0):

You could use a Regex for that:

```
(await page.frame({
    url: /http:\/\/192.168.20.222:8080\/ords\/f\?p=150\:.*/
})).click('button[id="B5602689567386780"]');
```

Comment: it didn't work, put this:

await page.frame ({
      url: /http:\/\/192.168.20.222:8080\/ords\/f\?p=150\:.*/
}). click ('button [id = "B5602689567386780"]');

Comment: Could you try the edit? mind the parenthesis